# JavaScript filter objects based on multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I want to filter objects based on a set of arrays containing filter terms. It basically works until one of the filter arrays contains multiple terms. Here is the code:

```js
// the filters
const filters = {
 "eyeColor": ["blue"],
 "gender": ["male"],
 "age": ["33"],
 "tags": ["d3js", "vuejs"] // multiple terms in the filter array breaks the code (returns empty array)
}

// the data 
const users = [
 {
  "age": "33",
  "eyeColor": "blue",
  "tags": "d3js, max, grotesk",
  "gender": "male",
 },
 {
  "age": "31",
  "eyeColor": "blue",
  "tags": "vuejs, adrian,  serif",
  "gender": "male",
 },
 {
  "age": "37",
  "eyeColor": "brown",
  "tags": "vuejs, max,  mono, d3js",
  "gender": "female",
 },
 {
  "age": "33",
  "eyeColor": "blue",
  "tags": "vuejs, markus, grotesk",
  "gender": "male",
 },
]

// the filter function
let results = users.filter(function (object) {
 return Object.entries(filters).every(function ([key, value]) {  
  return value.every(function (filter) {
   return object[key].includes(filter)
  })
 })
});
console.log(results);
```

I get an empty array, while the expected result would be:

```
{
   "age": "33",
   "eyeColor": "blue",
   "tags": "d3js, max, grotesk",
   "gender": "male",
},
{
    "age": "33",
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "tags": "vuejs, markus, grotesk",
    "gender": "male",
}
```

How can I get the expected result?

Comment: Can you change the format of `users` so that `tags` will also be an array of "tags" instead of a string?

Comment: I guess theoretically this would be possible. However, it's working now! Thank you

Comment: I just asked because with this approach the tag `serif` would also match `sans-serif`

Comment: Good thought! Thank you, I will keep that in mind while pursuing the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code uses

```
return value.every(function (filter) ...
//           ^^^^^
```

but you don't want to match *all* of the tags in the permitted array, only [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (*any*):

```
return value.some(function (filter) ...
//           ^^^^
```

Here's a demonstration:

```js
const filters = { "eyeColor": ["blue"], "gender": ["male"], "age": ["33"], "tags": ["d3js", "vuejs"] }
const users = [{ "age": "33", "eyeColor": "blue", "tags": "d3js, max, grotesk", "gender": "male", }, { "age": "31", "eyeColor": "blue", "tags": "vuejs, adrian,  serif", "gender": "male", }, { "age": "37", "eyeColor": "brown", "tags": "vuejs, max,  mono, d3js", "gender": "female", }, { "age": "33", "eyeColor": "blue", "tags": "vuejs, markus, grotesk", "gender": "male", }, ];

const filterEntries = Object.entries(filters);
const results = users.filter(user =>
  filterEntries.every(([key, permitted]) =>
    permitted.some(e => user[key].includes(e))
  )
);
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit - started writing an answer but saw no real need to finish once you posted yours, so I just added the runnable snippet.

Comment: I noticed that by filtering for `"gender": ["male"],` it returns also `female` because it contains "male". In some cases this is great, but would there be a solution to avoid this or is this locically inconsequent?

Comment: Right--the problem is that we're using `includes` which checks substrings. As mentioned above in the comments, it's poor design to have a comma-delimited list--better to use an array or `Set` of strings and then use `has` or `includes`. You can work around this using your current design with a regex that enforces word boundaries, like `e => new RegExp(`\\b${e}\\b`).test(user[key])`, or `split` the string on commas and call `includes` on that, but that's going to be a performance hit since it's done in a nested loop. Better to pre-process.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! In this case, I will try to follow the advice from above and design the data structure in a way that I have a list of strings rather than checking for substrings. Performance is a key aspect of this development.